# Using recursion to return first duplicate of a string. I can print but not return the answer and am not sure why

Tags: python, string, recursion

I am trying to return the first letter that is a duplicate within a string.  I am able to do it with the print method but always get none if I try to return the string.

This code works:

```
def recurringLetter(word):
    if word[0] == word[1]:
        print(word[0])
    elif len(word) == 0:
        print("None")
    else:
        recurringLetter(word[1:])

string = input()
recurringLetter(string)
```

But this code always returns none:

```
def recurringLetter(word):
    if word[0] == word[1]:
        return word[0]
    elif len(word) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        recurringLetter(word[1:])

string = input()
recurringLetter(string)
```

Comment: You have to `return` the result of the recursion i.e. `return recurringLetter(word[1:])`

Comment: Thank you Nick, that indeed did the trick.  Thanks for the edit too, I made a real mess of my first post. It looks a lot better now.

Comment: No worries. You just got the formatting character wrong, it should be three backticks ```, not three single quotes '''

Comment: Yeah was changing it and it said you already had. lol.  Your so quick and helpful thanks.